# Need help locating the patent on the hula hoop Chanel bag (circa 2013)

Tags: prior-art

I've searched the uspto.gov/patents website as well as google.com/patents and to no avail. I am new to this and I know it must exist. I would like to start a patent application on a similar item but would like to rule out prior art.

Comment: If this is patented at all, it would be design patent. Fashion is often not patented, but copyright might apply.

Answer (score 2):

Fashion, I believe, is more often protected by copyright than patents. If a patent were to exist, it would be a design patent. I went to https://patents.google.com/ and searched with ["Chanel, Inc" as the assignee](https://patents.google.com/?assignee=Chanel%2C%20Inc.). I get about 25 hits, but only one of them is related to a handbag and that covers an [ornamental clasp](https://patents.google.com/patent/USD696017S1/en?assignee=Chanel%2C%20Inc.&page=1). Most are patents on the composition of cosmetics. My guess is there isn't a design patent, but the bag is probably covered by copyright (probably registered). I don't know anything about copyright, but there are many search hits related to [fashion copyright infringement](https://www.google.com/#q=fashion+copyright+infringement+cases&*).

Comment: @S.Smith  You should wait a little while in case there is another useful answer, but once you do, it would be great to accept what you feel is the best answer by clicking the check mark icon.